# What is the importance of excluded values when solving rational expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I completely understand that they are the values that would result in a 0 in the denominator, which is undefined, which is a no no. I also know how to find them. I just don't get why they are important given the purpose is to SOLVE an equation. That means you end up with one answer. X can only be that one thing. So what is the point of specifying these excluded values that you can't input for X when there is literally only one thing it can be?

For example:

[image]

After cross multiplying and solving, the answer is X = 15. Done! That's the only thing it can be.

But I know the excluded values are 6 and 0. But why mention them. Only 15 works! Even if you COULD make X = 6, then cross multiplying results in 18 = 0. Obviously incorrect. If I did this with X = 0, I'd end up with -30 = 0. Also incorrect. But it would also be incorrect if I plugged in X = 1 or X = 100 or X = pi.

A more professional way of putting it is: doesn't solving for a single variable make specifying excluded values redundant?

Comment: Consider $\frac x{x-1}=\frac1{x-1}$.

Comment: There may be other cases where this the excluded values might matter: $x^2=x$ has two distinct solutions.  What about $\frac1{x^2}=\frac1x$?

Comment: Solving an equation does not necessarily mean there is only one solution.  For example, quadratic equations often have two solutions.  When solving rational equations, you would first come up with the _possible_ solutions, then determine which ones are extraneous by considering the restrictions.  Obviously, if the restrictions you have found have nothing to do with the possible solutions, then there is no need to mention them at all.

Comment: Thanks! I see now that there may be more than 1 solution to other equations. I guess in my specific example, they are extraneous, but in other cases it would be helpful to specify them.